# Filter collections by checking if filed contain value

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have collection with color_id, and have a table with name and colors_id field.Need to check or join values if it exists in filed, if - true, return name.
So final result should be collections of names where exists color_id.

screenshot of table with colors_id

[image: screenshot of table with colors_id]

screenshot of table with color_id

[image: screenshot of table with color_id]

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Wouldn't this be better with a many to many relationship between your user and colors table? Instead of keeping a list of ids in a column, a pivot table would match the id of the user and the ids of colors. Would be a lot easier for you to query and manage that kind of structure.

Comment: Dino Numić  - thanks for advice, will try!

Comment: Strawberry -  Read deep, I try to ask for approach, so what of example??!!! Thanks for minus...

Answer (score 0):

This how I would do it. First, create a pivot `php artisan make:migration create_color_user_table`.

In the up method of the migration

```
 $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
 $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

 $table->unsignedBigInteger('color_id');
 $table->foreign('color_id')->references('id')->on('colors')->onDelete('cascade');
```

In your user model

```
public function colors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Color::class, 'color_user');
    }
```

When you have a color or an array of colors to save to a user

```
$user->colors()->sync([1, 2, 3]);
```

If you want to get user colors

```
$user->colors;
```

If you want users with specific colors

```
$user = User::whereHas('colors', function ($q) use ($color){
    $q->where('id', $color->id);
})->get();
```